# yii cdbcriteria with join, group by and complex where clause

Tags: sql, yii

I have yii-powered application with big data records filter, which contains large and complex logic. I wrote correct sql query and tested out it.

```
SELECT
      c.`customer_id`       AS 'customer_id'
    , c.`status_id`         AS 'status_id'
    , c.`customer_name`     AS 'customer_name'
    , BIT_OR(r2c.`role_id`) AS 'roles_mask'
FROM
    `customers` AS c
LEFT JOIN
    `roles2customers` AS r2c
ON
    c.`customer_id` = r2c.`customer_id`
WHERE
        IF(   :status_mask = 0
            , c.`status_id` = 0
            , c.`status_id` & :status_mask <> 0
        )
    AND c.`customer_id` <> :customer_id
    AND c.`customer_name` LIKE concat(:customer_name, '%')
GROUP BY
    c.`customer_id`
HAVING
    IF(   :role_mask = 0
        , BIT_OR(r2c.`role_id`) = 0
        , BIT_OR(r2c.`role_id`) & :role_mask <> 0
    )
ORDER BY
    c.`customer_name` ASC
LIMIT
    :offset, :count
```

This query works correctly with simple ActiveRecord method findAllBySql:

```
$filtered_records = ModelClass::model()->findAllBySql( $sql, $params );
```

But my issue is to write application backend using CDbCriteria. So I need to build right criteria object and pass it into **findAll** method:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$filtered_records = ModelClass::model()->findAll( $criteria );
```

I opened [CDBCriteria reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) and saw many simple examples, but.. how can I specify JOIN and HAVING operations via criteria in my case?

My code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "
  c.customer_id AS 'customer_id',
  c.status_id AS 'status_id',
  c.customer_name AS 'customer_name',
  BIT_OR(r2c.role_id) AS 'roles_mask'
";
$criteria->offset = $offset;
$criteria->limit = $limit;
// how can I make valid r2c relation and group by via criteria? 
// and all another sql parts...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` parts are directly attachable in the same way as `condition`, `offset` and `limit`:

```
$criteria->group ='t.customer_id'
$criteria->having='IF(   :role_mask = 0
    , BIT_OR(r2c.`role_id`) = 0
    , BIT_OR(r2c.`role_id`) & :role_mask <> 0
)'
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is a bit more complex but can be done using `with`:

```
$criteria->with=array(
  'roles2customers'=>array(
    'alias'=>'r2c',
    'joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN',
    'condition'=>'
          IF(   :status_mask = 0
            , t.`status_id` = 0
            , t.`status_id` & :status_mask <> 0
          )
      AND t.`customer_id` <> :customer_id
      AND t.`customer_name` LIKE concat(:customer_name, '%')
    ',
  )
)
```

This relies on you setting up the basic relation `roles2customers` in the `ModelClass`.